# Linear Algebra Dimensions of $\mathrm{Nul}(A)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $T \colon \mathbb{R}^3 → V$ is a linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to some vector space $V$. Let $A$ represent the matrix of $T$. What are the possible dimensions of $\mathrm{Nul}(A)$? What would those dimensions mean geometrically?

Comment: What do you mean by "geometrically" ? We have $0\le \dim \ker(A)\le 3$.

Comment: Geometrically, in the sense of ℜ3.

Comment: Here we only use that $\dim (\mathbb{R}^3)=3$, and not really geometry in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Answer (score 1):

The nullity of T depends upon the Codomain as well but the fact is it can't be greater than 3 due to sylvesters law of nullity

Comment: But what are the possible dimensions of Nul(A)?

Comment: It can be $0,1,2,3$

Comment: @user312254 I have never heard about "Sylvester's law of nullity". Is it appropriate in this context ?

Answer (score 1):

Nul(T), that is preferably called the Kernel of $T$ (notation $Ker(T)$) is a vector subspace of $\mathbb{R^3}$. Thus its dimension can only be 0, 1, 2 or 3.

Answer (score -1):

$NullA$ is exactly as solving $Ax = 0$. Which is exactly $KerT$. Thus, Its dim is smaller or equal to 3.